# Cant get the download url from firebase storage

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I can successfully upload the image but can't  get the URL of the uploaded image
Also with the recent changes in the methods, I would like to write a cleaner code than this.

```
try {
          await FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref()
              .child('user_image')
              .child(authResult.user
                      .uid + //ref gives access to root cloud store , firebase manages all the tokens etc
                  '.jpg')
              .putFile(image);
        } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
        //Download the Url
        String url = await FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child('user_image')
            .child(authResult.user
                    .uid + //ref gives access to root cloud store , firebase manages all the tokens etc
                '.jpg')
            .getDownloadURL();
        print('Url' + url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use an `UploadTask` to get the download URL. A simpler version of your code is:

```
Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance .ref()
  .child('user_image')
  .child(authResult.user.uid+'.jpg')
try {
  await ref.putFile(image);
  String url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  print('Url' + url);
} on FirebaseException catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

What I've done above:

1. Create a variable for the `StorageReference`, so  that you only have to calculate it once and then both upload and get the download URL from that variable.
2. Move the exception handling to also cover the `getDownloadURL()` call, as you probably don't want to try and get the download URL when the upload fails.

With these two changes, it's pretty idiomatic and really close to the FlutterFire documentation examples on [uploading files](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#uploading-files) and [getting download URLs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#download-urls).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you Puf

Comment: The only change I made to this is to change `StorageReference` to just `Reference`. It has been changed.

Comment: Good catch @pannam. I updated the code on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use following code for uploading and downloading. You miss using uploadtask property.

```
   final photoRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("photos"); 
   UploadTask uploadTask = photoRef.child("$id.jpg").putFile(photo);
   String url = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();
```

Comment: Thanks I have upvoted your answer but I would like to use it without UploadTask. If I don't get any more answers I will accept your answer.